# Nested Class <List> : how to access nested class in list?

Tags: c#, .net

Basically i have one class with subclass(or nested class, inner class whatever it gets called)

I have no idea why i cant access (or list doesnt include nested class i guess)
nested class.

```
public static List<Tag> Tags = new List<Tag>();  

 //cureently selected tag,also random percentage related data
    public class Tag
    {
        public string name = null;
        public int dupe = 0;

        public int Tagindex = 0; 
        public int URLindex = 0;

        public class Type
        {
            public bool isArtist = false;
            public bool isGroup = false;
            public bool isTag = false;
            public bool isURL = false;
        }

        public class Score
        {

           //  0~10, sort them out!
            public bool isRated = false; //make true if user modifies score
            public int Story = 0;
            public int Reality = 0;
            public int Drawing = 0;
            public int memetic = 0;
            public string msg = null;

        }
```

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(gVar.Tags[i].Tagindex,gVar.Tags[i].name/*valid*/, gVar.Tags[i].Type.isArtist/*invalid*/);

//also invalid
Tag t1 = new Tag();
t1.Type.isArtist = true;
gVar.Tags.Add(t1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nested class is just a declaration of the class, same as if that class was not nested.
You have to instantiate an object of that type in order to access one of its properties.
For example:

```
public class Tag
{
    public string name = null;
    public int dupe = 0;

    public int Tagindex = 0; 
    public int URLindex = 0;
    public Score Score { get; } = new Score() // declare a property of the nested type, and instantiate an object

    public class Type
    {
        public bool isArtist = false;
        public bool isGroup = false;
        public bool isTag = false;
        public bool isURL = false;
    }

    public class Score
    {

       //  0~10, sort them out!
        public bool isRated = false; //make true if user modifies score
        public int Story = 0;
        public int Reality = 0;
        public int Drawing = 0;
        public int memetic = 0;
        public string msg = null;

    }
```

And the usage:

```
Tag t1 = new Tag();
t1.Score.Story = 3;
```

By the way, it's not recommended to use public fields, use properties instead (such as the Score property in the code above).

Comment: Thank you so much. btw im newbie at c# programming, so i dont understand how "public score score {get;} = new score();" works or "instantiating". if u do have some more times to spare, can i ask how they works or any articles related to this?

Comment: btw, it throwes  CS0102 Error when i directly uses it. does renaming that to Score1 and using it is okay?

Comment: Yes, you're right. You can rename the property a you like.